# Move Ubuntu install to new drive from safe mode

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, fdisk, parted

Currently my linux system will not boot because the partition it is on has no space left at all. I get an error when I was able to log in that said: " Warning unable to write to /tmp ". Now, I cannot even log in. I am running a KDE plasma desktop and it freezes when I try to log in. I read that this is common when there is low or no disk space.

I got a new drive so that I could move the install over but I am having a bit of a hard time of it. Making a direct copy of the install does not work because it creates a partition of the same size. When I try to expand the drive with parted or resize2fs after I make the copy, it says the drive is not big enough.

Can I simply format the new unallocated disk, then copy my linux install over exactly as it was before some how? I only have access to parted and fdisk. I saw some guides with gparted, but I cannot install gparted because I have no space on my drive.
[lsblk output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSjR9.jpg) [image]

Comment: Done. The disk I am moving to is the nvme0n1

Comment: look bad to me, which disk is your ubuntu boot disk ? is `sda` a windows partition ? if `sdc3` is your ubuntu partition, try removing old files from `/var/log` (this will allow you to boot at least)

Comment: Ok will try that. Would booting into live usb do anything? Ubuntu was installed on sdc. sda containts windows install, and the nvme partitions are a copy of my windows install (I am moving that to this disk as well.)

Comment: Often easier to just do a new install and then copy /home over with rsync. I was using Ubuntu, but tried Kubuntu on my HDD. Liked it and installed again into my SSD and just copied /home. My configuration settings were all there. Only if you edit system settings in /etc may you need those files also. And export list of installed applications to make it easy to reinstall those. I did that from my Ubuntu backup, but edited to not include everything, since Kubuntu has different default apps.

Comment: It seems like that is the only thing that’s going to work. Thanks @oldfred9